# How to get a users list by who created them?

Tags: user-roles, capabilities, users

I have two users with the capability to create other users. But their roles are not same.

1. Tom     - Role is Administrator
2. Jackie  - Role is CMS Manger (a custom created role)

Both have capability to create new users.
`CMS Manger` gets this capability by following code:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'add_caps_to_custom_roles' );
function add_caps_to_custom_roles() {
  $caps = array(
    'list_users',
    'edit_users',
    'create_users',
    'delete_users',
  );
  $roles = array(
    get_role( 'CMS Manager' ),
  );
  foreach ($roles as $role) {
    foreach ($caps as $cap) {
      $role->add_cap( $cap );
    }
  }
}
```

I have 120 users in the site now. But do not know who created whom.
I want a list that shows :

- List of users created by `tom`- Tom's users
- List of users created by `jackie`- Jackie's users

I was referring this for a while : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_by
But seems that function has `NO` solution for the above type of list.

How can I create those lists?

Comment: Who created a user is not stored anywhere, you will need to store that information at your own. You could use user meta fields and then use [WP_User_Query to get the users by custom fields parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters).

Comment: yup.. I can do that after the user registration using the hook `user_contactmethods`. Is there any way to add a custom field during a `NEW` user registration? Now I am looking for a solution by using the hook `user_new_form`whicj introduced in WP 3.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found it.

```
/*** Adding extra field to get the the user who creates the another user during ADD NEW USER ***/
function custom_user_profile_fields($user){
    if(is_object($user))
        $created_by = esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'created_by', $user->ID ) );
    else
        $created_by = null;
    ?>
    <h3>Extra profile information</h3>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="created_by">Created By</label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="regular-text" name="created_by" value="<?php echo $created_by; ?>" id="created_by" /><br />
                <span class="description">The person who creates this user</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php
}
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'custom_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'custom_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( "user_new_form", "custom_user_profile_fields" );

function save_custom_user_profile_fields($user_id){
    # again do this only if you can
    //if(!current_user_can('manage_options'))
      //  return false;

    # save my custom field
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'created_by', $_POST['created_by']);
}
add_action('user_register', 'save_custom_user_profile_fields');
add_action('profile_update', 'save_custom_user_profile_fields');
```

And then `querying` the users by the custom field `created_by`.. That's it..

Comment: you put this in custom_functions.php or fuctions.php right? thanks for this!

Comment: @BrockVond Yes. I put this in my `functions.php`

Answer (score 0):

I used the plugin Snippets to put this and other custom functions into the site. Keeps the functions.php file clean.

Comment: You can also make a simple plugin yourself. I'm always a bit nervous about giving site admins a way to run arbitrary PHP code from the dashboard.